# Included navigation menu php on click svg change with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I will try to make this short. 
I have php navigation page, in which i have a table with objects in which are SVGs. [I chose table because they can be automatically adjusted to screen size without extra coding]
SVGs are made in illustrator and modified with css and javascript with external `svg.js` in which are my svg functions i made myself. [probably mistake but in every svg object (I have 4) has its own `svg.js` imported.]

I have `index.php` in which are included footer and navigation menu phps and i plan to dynamically shift with ajax contents of the page via navigation menu with event onclick on svg.

So the tree looks like this :

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <!--included navigation.php -->
  </header>
  <section>
    <!-- included main content -->
  </section>
  <footer>
    <!-- included footer.php -->
  </footer>
</body>
```

and the navigation.php :

```html
<!-- this is navigation -->

<table>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <object data = "svg"> </object>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <object data = "svg"> </object>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <object data = "svg"> </object>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <object data = "svg"> </object>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <object data = "svg"> </object>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <h3> nav text </h3>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <h3> nav text </h3>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <h3> nav text </h3>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <h3> nav text </h3>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href = "#" >
        <h3> nav text </h3>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And svg inside an object :

```html
<svg id = "someid">
<style>
  //some css , fallback for javascript some are with !important
</style>

<g id = "icon">
the svg here
</g>

<defs>
  <script type = "text/ecmascript" xlink:href="../../../javascirpt/svg.js" ></script>
  <script type = "text/javscript" >
    and js here
  </script>
</defs>

</svg>
```

And this is segmented for a reason. I figured that it is better to make several smaller http request by server than one biiiiiiiig one. Index part of the website loads in about .6-.9 s so it is pretty quick. And this code works on mobile and on TV [except SVG on TV , that needs some modifying].

...Now I have a problem. I want to change pages in the main.php in the index.php with the click on object/svg with ajax. But the browser [chrome] cant access the svgs, when they are loaded, from the console. And any javascript I made in the index.php does not recognize the SVGs that are loaded by server with include. 
Now I tried to make `svg.js` more manageable by storing array of booleans and assign each boolean into a svg and handling it with event listeners then returning it to the `svg.js` evaluating it again and sending it back checking the value of that and all SVG buttons with setInterval by 1s. And if i start clicking on svgs they become all messed up. [phantom activation, CSS gets broken]

there is just one thing... i am trying not to include external libraries if not necessary ... so pure js and/or css and/or php if possible.
is there any way to send requests on client side to change 2 parts of the page but that parts are in different files ? 
Or do i have to code from the start again ... there is that option... but that is last resort. -.-
any further reading on this topic is well advised :D
if more code is necessary ... i can post some of it on codepen or something like that.

Comment: So you just want an svg that you can click and modify with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fine...

#### Keep it simple

If you use A links in svg you should be able to attach javascript events to them.
And then elaborate from there.

1. request
2. no image requests
3. multiple links
4. One svg

```js
var alink = new Array(3);
alink[0] = document.getElementById("circ1");
alink[1] = document.getElementById("circ2");
alink[2] = document.getElementById("circ3");

for (var i=0; i<alink.length; i++) {
  alink[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /*add ajax here*/
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-text");
  });
}
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}
#circ1 {
  fill: red;
}
#circ1:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
#circ2 {
  fill: purple;
}
#circ2:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
#circ3 {
  fill: brown;
}
#circ3:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">some text</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle data-text="red" id="circ1" cx="10" cy="50" r="10" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle data-text="purple" id="circ2" cx="35" cy="50" r="10" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle data-text="brown" id="circ3" cx="60" cy="50" r="10" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

This can also be modified by javascript when used inline.

Comment: WHAT A COMPLEX SERIES OF LOTS OF ELEMENTS! ... man :D i just love that sentence.  
i must say that i love the idea of one unique svg... and it will scale... so it is perfect for this part. 
but i have a question ... i would like to avoid the anchor tag and make transition with ajax. Because every anchor redirects page and i would like to try to make it all in 1. 
can ajax grab the svg element ?

Comment: ajax is javascript and svg is html so there is no reason why this should not work. You can add click event listener to the svg elements and then do a ajax request when they are clicked, thats no problem.

Comment: Here i edited as far as i can. I'm not really good with ajax, so i hope you can implement it yourself.

Comment: I will try that, and give update. Also, thanks Persijin :D

Comment: sorry ... not good. 1 svg with all scales good but the distance between elements is still javascript based... and because of illustrator i need to change viewbox settings and margin for every element. i need that distance to be flexible. I end up with more js for maintaining responsiveness than i had before.

Comment: Then our doing it wrong. you need to handle the image canvas statically so you should never change the viewbox with javascript. If you want to animate it then use javascript. A svg is by default 100% responsive all the time. How are you using javascript to "maintain" responsiveness?

Comment: ell lets say i have a header which is contained within center_margin element whose centers and 
defines the website main content area. Navigation is inside that rectangle made of centreline and
 header's height ... the navigation by itself is composed of svg graphics and text beneath every svg. 
 Because of screen sizes, and ratio between header's height and center_margins width, the svgs does 
 not need to be smaller, but sometimes they need to be bigger but with smaller 'margin'.

Comment: well because i work in ilustrator [ and he exports as width , height and viewbox and all other position elements ]
 i have to change the x,y coordinate of the view box of every single svg element. and sometimes their width and height...
 now i made formula for that and shorten javascript with that. But it is still pretty long. And my icons are complex. 
 so if i move one part of element an mm, the whole icon is wack.   so mostly i use element.style['viewbox/top-min/etc'] = assigneed.value;
[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)

Comment: @Danilo i would recommend going to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs. 
But you should add the things your going to move to groups and then edit the x and y of those groups. but if its all illustrator generated that can be a hazzle.